# php iphone push notification not reaching everyone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have the following code to send push notifications but it doesn't seem to be arriving to everyone, any ideas please? i looked here and online and it seems the code is correct so I'm puzzled, specially that I am always getting 'message successfully delivered'

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'production.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$err = '' ;
$errstr = '';
//$fp = stream_socket_client(   'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'type' => $type,
    'id' => $id
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

foreach ($devices as $deviceArray) {
$regId = $deviceArray['device_id'];


// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $regId ) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

ob_flush();
flush();
 }


// Close the connection to the server
 fclose($fp);
```

Comment: If the person haven't authorized your app to send push notifications, they won't received the push notification. Maybe you should ask those person to look if they have authorized your app ? They can see it in `Settings` > `Notification Center`

Comment: the phones not receiving are authorized, when i send to few recipients it works, but when all, not everyone gets it

Comment: use a time to between push's. In the end of looping add this code: ` usleep(1000000);`

Comment: Make sure the connection to APNS isn't closed from Apples side before you can send all notifications. More here: http://redth.codes/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/